# Performance of browser plugin based RIA vs. Java Script based RIA

Tags: javascript, silverlight, performance, extjs, browser-plugin

For my data intensive web application (heavy forms & complex reports), from performance standpoint, which is better ... a browser plug-in based RIA (say SilverLight) or Java Script based RIA (say ExtJS)?

At this moment, we can avoid the discussion of plug-in availability, etc. My only focus is performance. Reasoning will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say because it depends on so many variables.  But you might want to check out [Bubblemark](http://bubblemark.com/).  On that particular benchmark, Silverlight 3.0 (with bitmap caching enabled) does well, but a lot depends on the browser you're using.  Javascript with Chrome comes pretty close to Silverlight's rendering performance.  See also http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqjidzjkMM0.

If you use Silverlight and can access your WCF backend using Net.TCP, you can get pretty good data access performance as well.  I would expect it to be somewhat faster than JavaScript (since it doesn't have the HTTP overhead), but I don't know how it would compare to accessing FMS via RTMP.

Comment: Just one caveat - the Bubblemark, while very impressive and a good baseline for comparative performance, plays very well to Silverlight's biggest strengths - the CacheAsBitmap on the "balls" make it win handily (at least on every system I've seen it run on).

Not knocking Silverlight at all - its faster than hell and it pays my bills professionally - but be careful when attributing one performance test to its general performance overall. :)

Answer (score 2):

Computationally, Silverlight will win out compared to Javascript, no contest, especially with Silverlight 4 (twice as fast computationally). But I don't think raw number crunching performance is necessarily the most important thing, Chrome's Javascript engine is 10x faster than IE8's, but a web application in ExtJS isn't nearly 10x more responsive. How fast the object model is manipulated seems more important and HTML seems to be at a disadvantage here, because it's not really built for complex controls like grids in ExtJS.

If you look at the HTML generated by an ExtJS grid [here](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html), it goes 13 layers deep from the outmost container of the grid to the content of a cell. All those layers to trick HTML and CSS into doing the right thing.

And while I'm speculating a bit, it stands to reason that Silverlight's object tree is a lot flatter, because well, it *can* be as it's built to do the things it does. Add to that Silverlight's hardware acceleration and it will definitely win out in the performance department, but regardless of that I also think that performance is not very quickly a bottleneck when using a framework like ExtJS. It's still fast enough, usually.